# Finding NR of row with specific conditions (using next line)

Tags: awk

Guys I have a file like this

```
NR   column
1    1
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    1
7    1
8    1
9    1
10   0
11   0
12   0
13   1
14   1
```

What I need is to find the NR what will tell me where there are 1.

so my ideal output should tell me from NR=1  - 2 (there are 1s, then), NR=6  - 9, NR=13 - 14

or

```
1
2
6
9
13
14
```

Since, I think is easier not consider in the output the first row and the last. I expect that the output is

```
2
6
9
13
```

I've been trying a way to use getline but unsuccessfully.
I am sure there is an easy way to do this, help?

Thanks

Comment: Does your output correctly match up with your input file?  For example, it seems to me, the output would be "1, 3, 6, 10, 13"

Comment: If what you posted as expected output IS correct then edit your question to explain why as it seems to be wrong, like @Brian suggests.

Comment: You are partially right.

What I am trying to do is to get the limits when the values are 1.

So the first change will be from 1 to 0, and the NR of the change would be 2. (Now, I am not considering the first row just for simplicity.)

The second change it is from 0 to 1 and that happens at NR=5 but I need the position of the next 1 so it is NR=6.

Comment: That makes no sense and I've no idea what you mean by `get the limits when the values are 1`. Again - **edit your question** to clarify your requirements.

Comment: If the third number was 10 then it would sort of make sense, as i would assume they wouldn't consider the first line to have changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
$ awk '!p&&$2==1{p=$1}
          p&&!$2{print p"-"($1-1);p=0} 
             END{if(p) print p"-"$1}' file
1-2
6-9
13-14
```

Comment: man, you've saved my life haha, I've been trying to solve this.....too much.
Thanks!!! 
at the end I get 13-13 but it is ok anyways. =)

Comment: sorry! fixed the typo on the END block.

Comment: You should mention this will only work in some awks (e.g. gawk) since referencing `$1` in the END section is undefined behavior per POSIX.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your output above was incorrect (and it should really be the line number where the 0/1 or 1/0 transition happens - so the lines would be: "1, 3, 6, 10, 13"), then an awk oneliner is:

```
awk 'prev!=$0{print NR};{prev=$0}' file
```

which says:

- for every line that doesn't match the prev line, print the line number, and
- for every line, save the prev line

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'NR>1 && $0!=prev{print NR} {prev=$0}' file
3
6
10
13
```

or for your updated requirements:

```
$ awk '$1!=prev{print NR-prev} {prev=$1} END{if (prev) print NR}' file
1
2
6
9
13
14
```

Comment: Why not only change prev on lines where it doesn't match.

Comment: Because, unless I change the first condition, then prev wouldn't be set for the first line. Just a style choice.

Answer (score 1):

```
{
  if (NR > 1 && last != $0) {
    print NR;
  }
  last = $0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way

```
awk '$2!=x{x=$2;print NR-!($2)}END{if(x)print NR}' file

1
2
6
9
13
14
```